# Yup get value of ref

Tags: yup

I have to calculate something with a reference to another field as part of my yup schema. I figured `ref` was the way to go, but that doesn't seem to have the actual value I'm trying to use. The only properties of the ref that seems to do what I'm trying to do is `getValue` which returns the type of the ref, but it requires a parameter of type `any`. This code snippet should hopefully illustrate my problem and show what I'm trying to do:

```js
const raceSchema = object({
    abilityBonuses: array()
        .of(
            object({
                bonus: number()
                    .min(-10, 'Bonus cannot be lower than -10')
                    .max(10, 'Bonus cannot be higher than 10')
                    .required('Bonus is required'),
                abilityScore: object({
                    id: string().required('Ability score id is required'),
                    name: string().required('Ability score name is required')
                })
            })
        )
        .required('Ability bonuses are required'),
    abilityBonusOptions: object({
        bonus: number()
            .min(-10, 'Bonus cannot be lower than -10')
            .max(10, 'Bonus cannot be higher than 10')
            .required('Bonus is required'),
        numberOfAbilities: number().lessThan(
            6 -
                ref<{ bonus: number; abilityScore: Item }[]>('abilityBonuses').getValue(
                    // What do I put here? Should I even be using getValue?
                ).length +
                1,
            'Sum of number of ability bonuses and ability bonus option number must be less than 6'
        )
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .transform() method to transform the value of a field before validation.

For example, if you have a field called "age" that is a number, you can use the .transform() method to transform the value of "age" into a string before validation:

```
age: string().transform(value => value.toString()).required()
```

If you have a field called "age" that is a number, you can use the .transform() method to transform the value of "age" into a string before validation:

```
age: string().transform(value => value.toString()).required()
```

Comment: What would I be using `transform` on in my code example? I don't see `transform()` with typescript's autocomplete on the ref.

Comment: You can use the .transform() method on any field.

For example, if you have a field called "age" that is a number, you can use the .transform() method to transform the value of "age" into a string before validation:

age: string().transform(value => value.toString()).required()

Comment: I don't really need to change the type of a field as part of validation. Rather, I am trying to access the value of one field from another field for validation.

Comment: You can use the .transform() method to transform the value of a field before validation.

For example, if you have a field called "age" that is a number, you can use the .transform() method to transform the value of "age" into a string before validation:

age: string().transform(value => value.toString()).required()

If you have a field called "age" that is a number, you can use the .transform() method to transform the value of "age" into a string before validation:

age: string().transform(value => value.toString()).required()

Answer (score 0):

Try the `test` function.

It could look something like this'ish:

````js
const raceSchema = object({
  abilityBonuses: array()
      .of(
          object({
              bonus: number()
                  .min(-10, 'Bonus cannot be lower than -10')
                  .max(10, 'Bonus cannot be higher than 10')
                  .required('Bonus is required'),
              abilityScore: object({
                  id: string().required('Ability score id is required'),
                  name: string().required('Ability score name is required')
              })
          })
      )
      .required('Ability bonuses are required'),
  abilityBonusOptions: object({
      bonus: number()
          .min(-10, 'Bonus cannot be lower than -10')
          .max(10, 'Bonus cannot be higher than 10')
          .required('Bonus is required'),
    numberOfAbilities: number()
      .test(
        'numberOfAbilitiesSum',
        'Sum of number of ability bonuses and ability bonus option number must be less than 6',
        function numberOfAbilitiesSum(numberOfAbilities) {
          const abilityBonusesSelected = this.parent.abilityBonusOptions;
          return abilityBonusesSelected.length + 1 < 6;
        }
      )
  })
});```
````